# bamboo-ruby plugin: Could not run ruby task: Unable to locate Runtime Manager installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano, bamboo

I am using `bamboo-ruby-plugin v2.5.` and `Atlassian Universal Plugin Manager Plugin`. I have properly installed rvm, bundler

In my server capabilities, path to the ruby executables are properly set:

Example:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby
```

***PROBLEM***

1. I have a task which checkout to the required github branch and it is running successfully
2. Next I have bundler task i.e `bundle install`.

Now running a plan is successfully running first task `checkout` but it is generating error for second task `bundler`

The extracted error log file is as follows:

```
simple  02-Jul-2014 10:49:01    Starting task 'bundle install' of type 'au.id.wolfe.bamboo.rake-bamboo-plugin:task.builder.bundler'
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01    Could not run ruby task: Unable to locate Runtime Manager installation.
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01    au.id.wolfe.bamboo.ruby.locator.RuntimeLocatorException: Unable to locate Runtime Manager installation.
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at au.id.wolfe.bamboo.ruby.locator.RubyLocatorServiceFactory.acquireRubyLocator(RubyLocatorServiceFactory.java:63)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at au.id.wolfe.bamboo.ruby.tasks.AbstractRubyTask.getRubyLocator(AbstractRubyTask.java:119)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at au.id.wolfe.bamboo.ruby.tasks.AbstractRubyTask.buildEnvironment(AbstractRubyTask.java:157)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at au.id.wolfe.bamboo.ruby.tasks.AbstractRubyTask.execute(AbstractRubyTask.java:73)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.executeTasks(TaskExecutorImpl.java:220)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.execute(TaskExecutorImpl.java:98)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.tasks.ExecuteBuildTask.call(ExecuteBuildTask.java:75)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.build(DefaultBuildAgent.java:186)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.waitAndPerformBuild(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:102)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent$1.run(DefaultBuildAgent.java:108)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.utils.BambooRunnables$1.run(BambooRunnables.java:49)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWith(ImpersonationHelper.java:31)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWithSystemAuthority(ImpersonationHelper.java:20)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper$1.run(ImpersonationHelper.java:52)
error   02-Jul-2014 10:49:01            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
simple  02-Jul-2014 10:49:01    Finished task 'bundle install'
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: How were you able to do it ??

Comment: It didn't worked at all for me ..... Still unresolved :(

Comment: After reading their comments and all I created a symlink in /usr/local of the rvm folder
`sudo ln -s /home/user/.rvm /usr/local/rvm`
It worked like a charm afterwards

Comment: Did that worked?? Actually, I was busy on another task, still I ll give it a try

Comment: Yes, They have written in their documentation saying they are looking in /usr and then in /usr/local instead of looking in PATH defined in profile... Still dont get it why they are doing so but yes it worked

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply. Can you paste me that documentation url please. I will give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63212/discussion-between-shreyas-agarwal-and-przbadu).

Answer (score 0):

Try following this guide. Seems like the executable is not set right.

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/06/building-ruby-projects-with-bundler-and-the-bamboo-ruby-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

https://github.com/alienfast/bamboozled-ruby-plugin

It offers a plan-wide ruby runtime selection.  Instructions are on the github readme.  This was forked from the plugin you are using now to add additional functionality.

Marketplace page:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.alienfast.bamboozled.ruby.bamboozled-ruby-plugin

Comment: I get the feeling it has the same problem, though, because I encountered that exact error message and got to this question while searching for it. :)

Comment: @Trejkaz it looks like based on the [issue you submitted](https://github.com/alienfast/bamboozled-ruby-plugin/issues/11) that you setup rbenv outside ~/.rbenv as [the rbenv readme suggests.](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#basic-github-checkout)  The plugin does make some assumptions that the ruby runtime managers were installed as recommended.

Comment: Ah, right... Yep, we set up rbenv in the shared dev environment so that we don't have to install it separately on every build slave. We have about 20 build slaves all together and find that it keeps things tidy if everything required to build is available from a single place (only one directory to sync when setting up new machines, only one place to look for problems, etc.)

Comment: @Trejkaz Why not sync the home dir (or parts of it)?  We have a dedicated user for CI so the homes are the same.  Most of the tooling you will see is setup based on the home, so I'm afraid you might be fighting an uphill battle.

Comment: Why not sync the home dir? Because some devs like to have their home directory the way they want it, which is fair enough, because they have to work in it. "Most of the tooling"?

Comment: The tooling we already have working is mostly based on using $PATH. Using the environment to specify the location you want tools to load from is old technology which works and which many other people rely on working, so I don't think it will suddenly stop working just because one guy thinks that everything should be in one location and one location only.

Comment: 1) It is open source and pulls are welcome, so you can make a change to the locator functionality (fairly easily) to fit your custom scenario.

Comment: 2) Second, this is a plugin for a Bamboo CI server.  Developer's environments should _absolutely_ be isolated from the environment used for a CI server.  A CI "continuous integration" server is intended to be run in a repeatable environment, and I would _not_ consider a developer's environment (home or path) to be stable since they are likely developing with it.  This is exactly the reason why all of the tooling in question (i.e. rvm and rbenv) recommend installing in a specific user's home by default.

Comment: 3) Third, just because we have used PATH for ages, doesn't mean it fits for every scenario.  One such scenario PATH does _not_ work is a shared server used by developers _and_ runs a CI process that is intended to be repeatable.

Comment: 4) Fourth, the home path I suggested possibly syncing is the CI server user's home, not a developer's home.  These should be two very separate things.

Comment: We don't actually share developer systems with the CI jobs, but (perhaps surprising to some) we find that developers sometimes also want to build the software, and thus want all the same tools on their systems. Whereas it's true that we could just let each dev install all their own stuff, we find it easier for new staff if the dev environment is a single thing they just dump in a location of their choice. But this is all sort of a moot point, because Bamboo is broken in other ways which prevent us using it anyway (namely, the complete lack of anything like matrix builds.)